# How to exposing CockroachDB using Ingress on Google Cloud for external loadtesting

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, cockroachdb, ycsb

For my current distributed databases project in my studies I should deploy a CockrouchDB Cluster on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine and run a YCSB Loadtest against it.

The YCSB Client is going to run on another VM so that the results are comparable to other groups results.

Now I need to expose the DB Console on Port 8080 as well as the Database Endpoint on Port 26257.

so far I started changing the cockraochdb-public service to `kind: NodePort` and exposing its ports using an Ingress. My current Problem is exposing both ports (if possible on their default ports 8080 and 26257) and having them accessible from YCSB.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cockroachdb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: cockroachdb-global-ip
    ingress.citrix.com/insecure-service-type: “tcp”
    ingress.citrix.com/insecure-port: “6379”
  labels:
    app: cockroachdb
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: cockroachdb-public
    servicePort: 26257
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /labs/*
        backend:
          serviceName: cockroachdb-public
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: cockroachdb-public
          servicePort: 26257
```

So far I just managed to route it to different paths. I'm not sure if this may work, because the JDBC driver used by YCSB is using TCP not http.

How do I expose two ports of one service using an Ingress for TCP?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on:

> How do I expose two ports of one service using an Ingress for TCP?

In general when an `Ingress` resource is referenced it's for `HTTP`/`HTTPS` traffic.

You cannot expose the `TCP` traffic with an `Ingress` like the one mentioned in your question.

> **Side note!**
>
> There are some options to use an `Ingress` controller to pass the `TCP/UDP` traffic ([nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)).

---

You could expose your application with service of type `LoadBalancer`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cockroach-db-cockroachdb-public
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 26257
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: grpc # (containerPort: 26257) 
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http # (containerPort: 8080) 
  selector:
    selector: INSERT-SELECTOR-FROM-YOUR-APP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> Above example is taken from `cockroachdb` Helm Chart with modified value:
>
> - `service.public.type="LoadBalancer"`

By above definition you will expose your `Pods` to external traffic on ports: `8080` and `26257` with a `TCP`/`UDP` LoadBalancer. You can read more about it by following below link:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Exposing apps: Creating a service of type LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer)*

---

> The YCSB Client is going to run on another VM so that the results are comparable to other groups results.

If this `VM` is located in `GCP` infrastructure you could also take a look on Internal TCP/UDP LoadBalancer:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Using an internal TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing)*

---

Also I'm not sure about the annotations of your `Ingress` resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cockroachdb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: cockroachdb-global-ip
    ingress.citrix.com/insecure-service-type: “tcp”
    ingress.citrix.com/insecure-port: “6379”
```

In `GKE` when you are creating an `Ingress` without specifying the `ingress.class` you are using: `gce` controller. The `ingress.citrix.com` annotations are specific to citrix controller and will not work with `gce` controller.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*